# How to deal with data in which users_ids belong to more than one category (Multilevel) using Random Forest?

Tags: classification, random-forest

I know it sounds trivial, but I could not find any ready answers for this. Suppose we have this kind of data and we want to predict some target values for several users.

```
target user_id value1  category ...
0        1       .425    Ab|Be
0        2       .325     Ab
1        3       .26     Ab|Ck
1        4       .28     Be|Ck|Ju|Po
0        5       .56      Ab|Ck
1        6       .25       Ck
```

My issue is: how to deal with this kind of data using a statistical learning technique such as RandomForest.

I tried to extend the database this way and, after that, to calculate averages for cateogories, but I am unsure whether this is the appropriate way:

```
target user_id value1  category ...
0        1       .425    Ab
0        1       .425    Be
0        2       .325    Ab
1        3       .26     Ab
1        3       .26     Ck
1        4       .28     Be
1        4       .28     Ck
1        4       .28     Ju
1        4       .28     Po
0        5       .56     Ab
0        5       .56     Ck
1        6       .25     Ck
```

As a matter of fact, I couldn not get better results with this approach. And it looks wrong to me.

Just dropping the column is not an option either, because I am sure that it is important for the prediction.

I also know there are straightforward ways of modeling this with bayesian statistics and employing a software like Jags, but I am refering in this case to RandomForest.

What would you suggest?

Comment: I would like to hear more of how the data was obtained and if users occur several times. To include user_id could be problematic if each sample is an observation of a given user, and over time several observations are acquired. At the first observation of an user, predictions based on a user_id is useless. Thus, although this is not a time series forecasting, if samples are collected over time, and predictions are made online, batch modelling may not be useful in practice and batch cross-validation (nFold-CV, OOB-CV) over-optimistic. If so, back testing is needed.

Comment: **A person should only be judged by his past actions, not future,**  unless we're speaking of the Sci-Fi movie *Minority Report* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, this is your dataset:

```
> dataset <- structure(list(
    target = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
    user_id = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"),
    value1 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c(".25", ".26", ".28", ".325", ".425", ".56"), class = "factor"),
    category = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Ab", "Ab|Be", "Ab|Ck", "Be|Ck|Ju|Po", "Ck"), class = "factor")),
  .Names = c("target", "user_id", "value1", "category"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Each of your `user_id`s is a member of one or more classes. So just create dummy variables for all possible classes and put in a 1 (or TRUE) if that `user_id` is a member of that class. Again in R:

```
> foo <- strsplit(as.character(dataset$category),"\\|")
> bar <- unique(unlist(foo))
> dataset.new <- cbind(dataset,t(sapply(foo,function(xx)table(factor(xx,levels=bar)))))
> dataset.new
  target user_id value1    category Ab Be Ck Ju Po
1      0       1   .425       Ab|Be  1  1  0  0  0
2      0       2   .325          Ab  1  0  0  0  0
3      1       3    .26       Ab|Ck  1  0  1  0  0
4      1       4    .28 Be|Ck|Ju|Po  0  1  1  1  1
5      0       5    .56       Ab|Ck  1  0  1  0  0
6      1       6    .25          Ck  0  0  1  0  0
```

Now you can start classifiying, including membership in the various classes (and `value1`) as predictors. (Make sure your 0-1 `target` is interpreted as class memberships, not numerics.)

```
> dataset.new$target <- factor(dataset.new$target)
> library(randomForest)
> model <- randomForest(target~value1+Ab+Be+Ck+Ju+Po,dataset.new)
> model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = target ~ value1 + Ab + Be + Ck + Ju +      Po, data = dataset.new) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 50%
Confusion matrix:
  0 1 class.error
0 3 0           0
1 3 0           1

> model$importance

       MeanDecreaseGini
value1       1.05986667
Ab           0.47546667
Be           0.11180000
Ck           0.45940000
Ju           0.09733333
Po           0.10820000
```